# Running Concurrent thread execution

Tags: concurrency, jmeter

I am using `jmeter` tool for load testing. I want to execute all threads are in simultaneously (at the same time).

So I configured

```
No of Threads:20
Ramp-up period:Empty
Loop Count:1.
```

Now I run the `jmeter` tool.

After getting the result, I saw the result in *view results in Table*.
From this **start time** is displayed.i.e **Threads are executed one by one not simultaneously**. I included the image also.

Could you tell me how to run the concurrent threads simultaneously?

[Starting Time for threads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZveE.png)

Comment: Are 20 CPU cores availalable to your threads? This is a prerequisite for simultaneous execution.

Comment: yes.i want to execute simultaneously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `Synchronizing Timer` in your test plan
[image]

Comment: Thank you for spending your precious time.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a [Synchronizing Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) to your Test Plan.